# Can the result of a bitwise AND operator be negative (in Java)

Tags: java, operators, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I have the following piece of code:

```
int SOME_MASK = 0x0000ffff;

int value = /* some value */;
int something = SOME_MASK & value;

// WHY IS "something" guaranteed to be non-negative ?
if (something != NEGATIVE_CONSTANT) {
    // do something here....
}
```

I keep getting the [FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) analysis warning:

> Correctness - Bad comparison of nonnegative value with negative
>   constant This code compares a value that is guaranteed to be
>   non-negative with a negative constant.

The warning pops up for the line where comparing the bitwise AND result with the negative constant.

I am not sure why a Bitwise AND result is guaranteed to be non-negative? is this always the case?

Comment: How have you declared `SOME_MASK`?

Comment: Kudos to FindBugs for being this smart. I've often seen bitwise operators being treated as "value becomes unknown".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result of bitwise-AND can be negative, e.g. `(-1) & (-1)` is definitely `-1`.

However, if either operand is nonnegative, the result must also be nonnegative. This is because in 2's complement representation, a negative number must have its 31st bit set, and a nonnegative number must have its 31st bit cleared. Since `&` will set a bit only if both operand's bit is set, the result is negative if and only if both inputs are negative.

Since `SOME_MASK = 0xffff` is positive, the result of `SOME_MASK & value` will never be negative.

Answer (score 3):

When `SOME_MASK` starts with a '0' bit, the result of `SOME_MASK & value` must be positive.

Answer (score 2):

`something` is guaranteed not to be negative because Java's signed `int` type uses the most significant bit for sign, and that bit is cleared (`0`) in `SOME_MASK`. Since `something` is the result of something being ANDed with that mask, it can't have that bit set, so it can't be negative.

Answer (score 2):

> Can the result of a bitwise AND operator be negative (in Java)

In general - Yes.

In the case of your example - No.

In Java, integers are represented in [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) signed binary representation.  One characteristic of this representation is that the most significant (i.e. left-most) bit is one for a negative number and zero for a positive number.

In your example, you are ANDing with `0x0000ffff`, and that is setting the top 16 bits to zero.  That means that the result of that expression *cannot* be a negative number.

---

By contrast, if you ANDed with `0xffff0000`, the result *could* be negative.

Answer (score 1):

The bitwise AND of two negative integers is always negative.  The bitwise AND of two integers, where one or both are positive, is always positive.  To see why, think about the binary representation, and what happens to the highest bit.